# How to change an awk script to work on Solaris

Tags: bash, shell, awk, solaris

the below script is bin-packing First-fit algorithm,the script is running normally on ubuntu Linux and i can call bin_packing.awk, but when I try to run it on unix solaris I'm getting errors

`bin_packing.awk`:

```
function first_fit(v, file) {
    # find first bin that can accomodate the volume
    for (i=1; i<=n; ++i) {
        if (b[i] > v) {
            b[i] -= v
            bc[i]++
            cmd="mv "file" subdir_" i
            print cmd
            # system(cmd)
            return
        }
    }
    # no bin found, create new bin
    if (i > n) {
        b[++n] = c - v
        bc[n]++
        cmd="mkdir subdir_"n
        print cmd
        # system(cmd)
        cmd="mv "file" subdir_"n
        print cmd
        # system(cmd)
    }
    return
}
BEGIN{ if( (c+0) == 0) exit }
{ first_fit($1,$2) }
END { print "REPORT:"
    print "Created",n,"directories"
    for(i=1;i<=n;++i) print "- subdir_"i,":", c-b[i],"bytes",bc[i],"files"
}
```

and to call it:

```
$ find . -type f -iname '*pdf' -printf "%s %p\n" \
  | awk -v c=100000 -f bin_packing.awk
```

This will create a list of files with the file size in bytes in front of it., value c to be the maximum size a directory can have in bytes. The above value c=100000 is only an example, This will create output like:

```
...
mv file_47 subdir_6
mv file_48 subdir_6
mv file_49 subdir_5
mv file_50 subdir_6
REPORT:
Created 6 directories
- subdir_1 : 49 bytes 12 files
- subdir_2 : 49 bytes 9 files
- subdir_3 : 49 bytes 8 files
- subdir_4 : 49 bytes 8 files
- subdir_5 : 48 bytes 8 files
- subdir_6 : 37 bytes 5 files
```

it shows the below erros if i try to run it on Solaris, and based on feedback -printf is a GNU feature, so it isn't available in non-GNU versions of find

> ```
> find: bad option -printf
> find: [-H | -L] path-list predicate-list
> awk: syntax error near line 1
> awk: bailing out near line 1
> ```

Comment: That script is actually quite dangerous -- if a file had a name like `$(rm -rf ~)`, for example, running `system()` with a command that included it would delete all your files. `system()` and equivalents are very much best avoided in awk. (`mv "$file" "$other_file"` is safe in bash because the shell doesn't parse expansion results as syntax, but when you pass a name into the shell pre-expanded you don't get those safeties).

Comment: ...frankly, insofar as your script is just doing dictionary lookups and integer math, if you have a recent version of bash you could implement it in native bash and not need awk; if you *don't* have recent bash, it would probably be pretty easy as a perl script (and that would also give you a native `stat` call to be able to look up sizes).

Comment: That specific awk error message means you're running old, broken awk (/bin/awk - the default on Solaris unfortunately). Never use that awk because it's, well, old and broken. On Solaris use /usr/xpg4/bin/awk instead (or xpg6 if you have it). Someone will probably pop up and say "or nawk" - ignore that advice, nawk is better than old, broken awk (sometimes named or aliased to `oawk`) but it's still much older and further from POSIX compliance than the xpg* awks I recommended.

Comment: If you're going to use that script to generate mv and mkdir commands at least make sure the file and directory names are quoted properly. Change every `cmd="mv "file" subdir_" i` or similar to `cmd="mv \047"file"\047 \047subdir_" i "\047"` and every `cmd="mkdir subdir_"n` to `cmd="mkdir \047subdir_"n"\047"` to wrap everything in single quotes (produced by the `\047`s).

Comment: To see the difference: `echo '$(echo "hello world")' | awk '{cmd="echo "$0; system(cmd)}'` outputs `hello world` while `echo '$(echo "hello world")' | awk '{cmd="echo \047"$0"\047"; system(cmd)}'` outputs `$(echo "hello world")`, i.e. the former exposes the string to the shell for interpretation/execution while the latter doesn't and so is much safer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using `nawk` (new awk) or `/usr/xpg4/bin/awk` (POSIX awk) with Solaris. `awk` is the original legacy version with  Perl to glean the same info as find's -printf:

Here is the soluation:

```
$ find . -type f -name '*.pdf' -print | perl -lne '$,=" "; @s=stat $_; print $s[7],$_, $s[2]' | nawk -v c=5000000 -f bin_packing.awk
```

Answer (score 0):

to save the problem with the missing --printf find feature, you can try with:

```
find . -type f -iname '*pdf' -exec stat --printf="%s %n\n" {} \; \
| awk -v c=100000 -f bin_packing.awk
```

Comment: great but you soluation is not working with solaris`-printf`is a GNU feature, so it isn't available in non-GNU versions of find, also Solaris doesn't understand` -iname` only `-name` , i used Perl to glean the same info as find's`-printf ` and its worked